# Can lists be mutated?

Tags: python, list, mutable

When I type following code,

```
x=[1,2,4]
print(x)
print("x",id(x))
x=[2,5,3]
print(x)
print("x",id(x))
```

it gives the output as

```
[1, 2, 4]
x 47606160
[2, 5, 3]
x 47578768
```

If lists are mutable then why it give 2 memory address when changing the list x?

Comment: The answer from @iCodez is spot on. You should carefully read the ["Naming and Binding" section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) of the Python docs, which explains exactly what is happening when Python executes an assignment statement, `variable_name = ...`

Answer (score 16):

You created a **new list object** and bound it to the same name, `x`. You never mutated the existing list object bound to `x` at the start.

Names in Python are just references. Assignment is binding a name to an object. When you assign to `x` again, you are pointing that reference to a different object. In your code, you simply created a whole new list object, then rebound `x` to that new object.

If you want to *mutate* a list, call methods on that object:

```
x.append(2)
x.extend([2, 3, 5])
```

or assign to indices or slices of the list:

```
x[2] = 42
x[:3] = [5, 6, 7]
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(x)
4301563088
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x[:2] = [42, 81]
>>> x
[42, 81, 3]
>>> id(x)
4301563088
```

We changed the list object (mutated it), but the `id()` of that list object did not change. It is still the same list object.

Perhaps this excellent presentation by Ned Batchelder on Python names and binding can help: [*Facts and myths about Python names and values*](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 14):

You did not mutate (change) the list object referenced by `x` with this line:

```
x=[2,5,3]
```

Instead, that line creates a *new list object* and then reassigns the variable `x` to it.  So, `x` now references the new object and `id(x)` gives a different number than before:

```
>>> x=[1,2,4]  # x references the list object [1,2,4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 4]
>>> x=[2,5,3]  # x now references an entirely new list object [2,5,3]
>>> x
[2, 5, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However I found it difficult to understand why `x=2*x` creates a new object and binds x to it instead of just mutating the original object. Similar for `x.append`. If I write `x.append`, then the address keeps the same, but if I write `x2=x.append`, then x2 points to a new object. (I cannot write `x=x.append` because `append()` does not return a new list) I think I need to fully understand the assignment semantic.

Answer (score 4):

You are not mutating the list, you are creating a new list and assigning it to the name `x`. That's why `id` is giving you different outputs. Your first list is gone and will be garbage-collected (unless there's another reference to it somewhere).