# Remove dependency between python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, dependencies, connection

I have a question about some python dictionary behavior i haven't seen yet. (i am using python3.6)

I have a dictionary **first_dict** containing two keys "kk" and "aa", both linked to a list. Then i make a new dict namly **second_dict**. Now comes the strange thing, whenever i make a variable like **fractions** and edit this value, it automatically updates my dictionary. So i assume python automatically makes a connection between dictionary derived variables.

```
def main():

    first_dict = {"kk": [0.0, 1.0], "aa": [0.5, 1.0]}
    second_dict = first_dict
    fractions = second_dict["kk"]

    fractions.pop(0) #del fractions[0] gives same result
    print(first_dict)  #{'kk': [1.0], 'aa': [0.5, 1.0]}
    print(second_dict) #{'kk': [1.0], 'aa': [0.5, 1.0]}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My question is can i remove these connections, i found a solution to remove the connection between **fractions** and my **second_dict** by using:

```
fractions = list(second_dict["kk"])
```

however i could not find a solution to remove the connection between **first_dict** and **second_dict**.
So i want to change **second_dict** and leave the **first_dict** unchanged.

Comment: The keyword for this behavior is "mutable", see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292174/are-python-lists-mutable . Your `second_dict` is indeed not a second dict, but a second name for the same dict.

Comment: the first solution in the "duplicate" post do not solve my problem. so dict2 = dict(dict1) and dict2 = dict1.copy() do not work. How come?

Comment: @candah: because `dict(dictionary)` and `dictionary.copy()` create a *shallow* copy, so the contained list objects in the values are still shared.

Comment: @candah: You really want to read [this article on Python names and references](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with dictionaries specifically.

First off, you never made a new dictionary (shallow copy). To do that:

```
new_dictionary = dict(old_dictionary)
```

Secondly, **lists are mutable**. When you shallow-copy you have the same references for the key values, so mutating an object manifests anywhere it is referenced. *Maybe* you want to `deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
new_dictionary = deepcopy(old_dictionary)
```

A better way is using immutable objects whenever possible (the equivalent for a `list` is usually a `tuple` in python).

Answer (score 4):

What you are really trying to say is that you want `first_dict` and `second_dict` to point to different objects, instead of the same one

This could be done by replacing

`second_dict = first_dict`

With

```
from copy import deepcopy
second_dict = deep_copy(first_dict)
```