# Why two different value of list is printing when the value of list is not changed?

Tags: python, list

In the following Python code value of `lis` is not changed, then why it is printing two different values?

```
lis = [[]]
x = lis[0]
print(lis)
x.append(1)
print(lis)
```

output:

```
[[]]
[[1]]
```

Comment: "value of lis is not changed" Why do you think so?

Comment: Another good post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292174/are-python-lists-mutable

Comment: after `x.append` python adds `1` in the list `x`.

Comment: and the list `x` is a sub-list of `lis`, and `x=lis[0]`, so this will change the value of list `lis`. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Because in python when you assign to var a list from another var, you won't get it's value directly. You only get a link to its address. To get a list from lis directly you need to write:

```
lis = [[]]
x = lis[0].copy()
```

This will create a new list for x and empty list would not change.

Answer (score 0):

As lis[0] and x are referenced to the same memory location, changes in x are causing changes in lis.

Instead use:

```
lis = [[]]
x = lis[0].copy()
print(lis)
x.append(1)
print(x)
```